# sql function without select/insert/delete/update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not so experienced with sql and this is my (maybe stupid) question:

I have the following query

```
select *
from myTable
where lower(replace(lastname, 'ü', 'ue')) = lower(replace(someStr, 'ü', 'ue'))
```

Is it possible to replace the

```
lower(replace(lastname, 'ü', 'ue')) = lower(replace(someStr, 'ü','ue'))
```

with a function?

Something like this:

```
select *
from idmanlight.nethz_user
where myFunction(lastname) = myFunction(someStr)
```

I tried to define the function this way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(IN str character varying) RETURNS void AS $$
LOWER(replace(replace(replace((str, 'ü', 'ue'), 'ä', 'ae'), 'ö', 'oe'));
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

but running it I get the error

> ERROR: Syntax error by »LOWER« SQL state: 42601 Character: 88

All the examples I found have always a select, delete, update, insert in the function's body.

It is actually possible to define a function which has no select, delete, update, insert in it?

I'm using PostgresSql 9.2.

Comment: I addition to Remi's answer: you should apply the `lower()` function to the argument not the result. Otherwise `Ä` would not be converted to `ae`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is due to an sql syntax and an incorrect return value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(str text) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT LOWER(replace(replace(replace((str, 'ü', 'ue'), 'ä', 'ae'), 'ö', 'oe'));
$$ IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE sql;
```

Alternative, more complete function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION translit(text)
    RETURNS text
AS $$
DECLARE
    _str    text := $1;
    _find   constant text :=    'ÀÁÂÃÄÅĀĄĂÆÈÉÊËĒĘĚĔĖÐÌÍÎÏĪĨĬĮİĲÒÓÔÕÖØŌŐŎŒÙÚÛÜŪŮŰŬŨŲÝŶŸ' ||
                                'àáâãäåāąăæèéêëēęěĕėðìíîïīĩĭįıĳòóôõöøōőŏœùúûüūůűŭũųýÿŷ' ||
                                'ÇĆČĈĊĎĐƑĜĞĠĢĤĦĴĶŁĽĹĻĿÑŃŇŅŊŔŘŖŚŠŞŜȘſŤŢŦȚÞŴŹŽŻ' ||
                                'çćčĉċďđƒĝğġģĥħĵĸķłľĺļŀñńňņŉŋŕřŗśšşŝșßťţŧțþŵžżź';
    _repl   constant text :=    'AAAAAAAAAAEEEEEEEEEEIIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOOOOUUUUUUUUUUYYY' ||
                                'aaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiioooooooooouuuuuuuuuuyyy' ||
                                'CCCCCDDFGGGGHHJKLLLLLNNNNNRRRSSSSSSTTTTTWZZZ' ||
                                'cccccddfgggghhjkklllllnnnnnnrrrsssssstttttwzzz';
BEGIN
    -- Bail if the string is empty.
    IF  _str = ''
    THEN
        RETURN _str;
    END IF;

    -- Common expansions.
    _str := replace(_str, 'ſ', 'SS');
    _str := replace(_str, 'ß', 'ss');
    _str := replace(_str, 'Å', 'AA');
    _str := replace(_str, 'å', 'aa');
    _str := replace(_str, 'Ĳ', 'IJ');
    _str := replace(_str, 'ĳ', 'ij');
    _str := regexp_replace(_str, '([ÄÆÖŒÜ])', E'\\1E', 'g');
    _str := regexp_replace(_str, '([äæöœü])', E'\\1e', 'g');

    -- Translate what's left.
    _str := translate(_str, _find, _repl);

    RETURN _str;
END;
$$ IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE plpgsql COST 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

don't return void. You have a syntax problem. It should return a string, and have a statement like:

```
RETURN LOWER(...)
```

or

```
RETURN SELECT LOWER(...)
```

Comment: The function also needs to be changed to `returns text` instead of `returns void`